# How can I view all my Tables in databse?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Have a database named ***GoogleAdsSupport*** how can i view all my tables in the Given database?

I am using **SQL Server 2008 R2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code:

`USE GoogleAdsSupport
 SELECT name FROM sys.tables`

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you want to list all the tables you have created in your database? If so, then the following will do that for you:

```
SELECT * FROm sys.tables
```